# How to calculate network and broadcast address using IP and CIDR on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, ip

In my database, the address range is stored in a single column, using the IP/CIDR notation.  This value contains the start and end IP addresses, but they need to be extracted, into the broadcast and network fields.  The start and end IP addresses are stored as a number.One of the post i read mentioned , IP is converted to an IP number using MySQL’s native inet_aton() function, and back to a dotted IP address using the inet_ntoa() function.So storing the addresses as numbers makes it more efficient to query the database.

As per my understanding using the IP and CIDR, it’s possible to calculate the broadcast address.
`The broadcast address is the network IP, plus,32 minus the CIDR,to the power of 2, minus 1`.

So, I ran the following SQL update to populate the two columns.

```
UPDATE blocks SET 
broadcast = (INET_ATON(SUBSTRING_INDEX(network_cidr, '/', 1)) + (POW(2, (32-SUBSTR(network_cidr, INSTR(network_cidr, '/')+1)))-1)), 
network = INET_ATON(SUBSTRING_INDEX(network_cidr, '/', 1));
```

but this is not working for me. Am i doing something wrong ?

Here is mysql table :

```
network_cidr    network broadcast
2001:1200::/32  (NULL)  (NULL)
2001:1208::/32  (NULL)  (NULL)
2001:1210:1000::/36 (NULL)  (NULL)
2001:1210:100:8000::/49 (NULL)  (NULL)
2001:1210:100::/49  (NULL)  (NULL)
2001:1210:101::/48  (NULL)  (NULL)
2001:1210:102::/47  (NULL)  (NULL)
2001:1210:104::/46  (NULL)  (NULL)
2001:1210:108::/45  (NULL)  (NULL)
2001:1210:110::/44  (NULL)  (NULL)
2001:1210:120::/43  (NULL)  (NULL)
2001:1210:140::/42  (NULL)  (NULL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is that your cidr addresses are IPv6 addresses. Unfortunately, according to the MySQL documentation, INET_ATON only works for IPv4 addresses. Use INET6_ATON instead. You may need to check your version of MySQL supports INET6_ATON.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html

Comment: thanks. yes it was suppose to be IPv4 address, and it is working fine with IPv4 addresses. I will look into INET6_ATON.